# Retrieve the parent component of an XSComponent in XSOM

Tags: java, xsd, xsom

I'm using the XSOM framework to parse a batch of XSD files, and then write them into a graph db.

For every XSDeclaration, there is a possibility to check whether or not they are local, or global. In other words, whether a component is declared in the root of the XSD files, or if it's part of an anonymous type.

I would like to be able to retrieve the global parent, of which the local component is a part of but I could not find such a method anywhere in the java doc.

For example:

```
<xs:group name="group">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="grEl1" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="grEl2" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="grEl3" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

When I have the XSElementDecl with name grEl1, I check if it's local which will return true. I would then like to be able to ask that XSElementDecl in some way, to give me it's parent, which is the XSModelGroupDecl with name group.

Thanks in advance :)